# What is Lévy measure? Why is it needed, and what is $(1\wedge|x^2|)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, economics

> A Borel measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is called a Lévy measure if
>   $\nu({0})=0$ and $\int_\mathbb{R}(1\wedge|x^2|) \, \nu(dx) < \infty .$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_models_with_long-tailed_distributions_and_volatility_clustering#Infinitely_divisible_distributions)

So, what exactly is $(1\wedge|x^2|)$? (Or rather correctly, what is the definition of levy measure saying?)

Edit: OK, but then why is levy measure needed?

Comment: What do you mean by "why is it needed"? The [Lévy-Khintchine decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process#L.C3.A9vy.E2.80.93Khintchine_representation) provides a way of characterizing any Lévy process in terms of three components (the Lévy triplet) - one of which is a measure called the Lévy measure.

Comment: Levy measure describes the distribution of the jumps of the process. For example, a Poisson process of parameter $c>0$ has the Levy measure $c\delta(x-1)$, implying that the jump of size 1 occurs with intensity $c$. (In general, the jump part of a Levy process is a compensated sum of the Poisson point process with characteristic measure as the Levy measure.)

Comment: @SangchulLee You mentioned that the levy measure of poisson process with rate c has levy measure $c\delta(x-1)$, could you please show the calculation explicitly?

Comment: @math101, Following the definition of Lévy measure as in the [Lévy-Kintchine formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lévy_process#L.C3.A9vy.E2.80.93Khintchine_representation), you can easily check that $\nu(x) = \lambda \delta(x-1)$ gives $$ \phi_{X_1}(\xi) = \mathrm{e}^{\lambda (e^{i \xi} - 1)}, $$ which is the characteristic function of the Poisson process.

Comment: yes. To match $c(e^{i\xi}-1)$ with $\int(e^{i\xi x}-1)\nu(dx)$. The first part, $e^{i\xi}=\int e^{i\xi x}\delta_1(dx)=\int e^{i\xi x} d\delta_1=e^{i\xi 1}=e^{i\xi}$. The 2nd part, we have $1=\int\delta_1(dx).$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$1\wedge|x^2|=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if} & |x|\gt1, \\ x^2 & \text{if} & |x|\leqslant1. \end{cases}$$